# Dynamic variable in Angular directive cannot be resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have a HTML table linked to a directive, I need to pass in a scope variable to the directive {{product.id}}, the product variable is set asynchronously in my controller. But when I try to retrieve the attribute in my directive link function like this:

```
$("#variants-dd").data('variant-source')
```

It always returned me NULL, I assume its because the product variable was set asynchronously. I also tried observe the product variable in my directive but still doesn't work.

Any idea?

```
    @app.directive 'myTable', ["$compile", ($compile) ->
      return {
        scope: {}
        link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
          options = {}
          if attrs.myTable.length > 0
            options = scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.myTable)
          else
            options = {
                bStateSave: true
                iCookieDuration: 2419200
                bJQueryUI: true
                bPaginate: false
                bLengthChange: false
                bFilter: false
                bInfo: false
                bDestroy: true
            }

          explicitColumns = []
          element.find('th').each (index, elem) ->
            explicitColumns.push($(elem).text())

          options["oLanguage"] = { "sInfo": "(_END_ of _TOTAL_)", "sInfoEmpty": "(0 of 0)"}

          if (attrs.aoColumns) 
            options["aoColumns"] = scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.aoColumns)
          else if explicitColumns.length > 0
            options["aoColumns"] = explicitColumns

          # aoColumnDefs is dataTables way of providing fine control over column config
          if attrs.aoColumnDefs
            options["aoColumnDefs"] = scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.aoColumnDefs)

          if attrs.fnRowCallback
            options["fnRowCallback"] = scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.fnRowCallback)

          scope.dataTable = element.dataTable(options)

      }
    ]
```

Controller:

```
  @ProductCtrl = ["$routeParams", "$scope", "Product", ($routeParams, $scope, Product) ->
    if $routeParams.id
      Product.get {id: $routeParams.id}, (order) ->
        self.original = order
        $scope.product = new Product(self.original)

      $scope.variantOverrideOptions = {
        sDom: 'rt'
        bRetrieve: true
        sPaginationType: "bootstrap"
        aaSorting: [[ 2, "desc" ]]
        bProcessing: true
        bServerSide: true
        bPaginate: true
        bStateSave: true
        iDisplayLength : 19
        fnCreatedRow: $scope.rowCompiler
        sAjaxSource: $("#variants-dd").data('variant-source')
        fnServerData: ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) ->
          $.ajax({
              "dataType": 'json', 
              "type": "GET", 
              "url": sSource, 
              "data": aoData, 
              "success": fnCallback
          }) 
      }
```

HTML table:

```
        <table 
            class="table data-table display"
            id="variants-dd"
            ao-columns="variantOverrideColumns"
            my-table="variantOverrideOptions"
            data-variant-source="/inventory/{{product.id}}/variants">
          <thead>
            <tr>
            <th width="15%">SKU</th>
            <th width="10%">Size</th>
            <th width="6%">Cost price</th>
            <th width="6%">Count on hand</th>
            <th width="7%">Minimum on hand</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Can you paste the complete controller code?

Comment: Yeah man, I'm sure we could figure this out for you, but not with what you've given us. You say the problem is in the directive, but we have no directive code to look at.

Comment: Sorry about that, here you go